# find derivative with 2 different constants

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maximum-likelihood

I have the following log-likelihood: 
$$l(\beta) = n \log\beta - (\beta + 1) \sum_{i = 1}^n \log(x_i)$$

the job is to find $l'(\beta)$ and show that the candidate $MLE$ is:
$$\hat{\beta} =\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log (x_i)} $$

so, we know that $x_i$ and $n$ are constants but then when it comes to differentiating $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log (x_i)$ is when i get confused as in theory the differential of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log (x_i)$ should be ${\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}}$ correct?

so this is what i have got to so far:
$$l'(\beta) = \frac{n}{\beta}- (1+0){\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}}$$ which simplifies to:
$$l'(\beta) =  \frac{n}{\beta} - {\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}}$$

so what am I doing wrong? any help please!

Comment: What is the variable in your expression? Is it $\beta$? And what's the difference between $x_i$ and $X_i$?

Comment: @Andrei $\beta$ is the parameter and $X_i$  is the variable and $x_i$ is an observation of that variable if that makes sense?

Comment: @RaulGonzales Note that the variable for the expression $l(\beta)$ is $\beta$ and thus $x_i$'s are constants for that expression. Thus, when you are differentiating wrt $\beta$, the derivative of $\beta \sum_{i = 1}^n \log (x_i)$ will be $\sum_{i= 1}^n \log (x_i)$ as that sum is effectively a constant in the expression.